# Unity Vuforia: Camera position is wrong when trying to draw a line with LineRenderer

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Hello im new at AR development, i've tried to make a simple script that takes the camera position and the position of some object in the world and then draw a simple line between them using LineRenderer.

The object is tied to an imagetarget and im running with the FIRST_TARGET setting (so the world should have its origin (0,0,0) on the imagetarget)

However the camera position seems to be wrong for me and i dont really understand why. What i want is a line from the center of the mobile (Camera) screen to some object in the world viewed using an imagetarget. I would love some help with my issue. The code for my script is here:

```
public class POILine : MonoBehaviour
{
//Camera
private GameObject camera;
//Gameobject of interest to point the user towards
public GameObject to;
private GameObject toParent;
private LineRenderer line;
public float lineWidthMultiplier = 0.5f;
private float distance;
public float distanceMin = 50f;
void Start ()
{
    camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
    line = this.gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();

    line.positionCount = 2;
    //Thickness of the line
    line.widthMultiplier = lineWidthMultiplier;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    TrackableBehaviour.Status toStatus = to.transform.parent.GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>().CurrentStatus;
    if (toStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED || toStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(camera.transform.position, to.transform.position);
        if (distance > distanceMin)
        {
            line.enabled = true;
            if (to != null)
            {
                //I think the error is here
                line.SetPosition(0, camera.transform.position);
                line.SetPosition(1, to.transform.position);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            line.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code works in editor if i make an empty gameobject a child of the camera and then place it in front of the camera in the editor. I can then use that gameobject as startpoint instead of the camera position. Still dont know why camera position doesnt work tho. Also wont work if i build to my phone

Comment: Nvm, above solution works even on the phone... i just forgot i had coded in the distance requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working, what i did was that i placed an empty gameobject as a child to the Imagetarget i was currently tracking, then i made it follow the ARCamera transform position.

Then the code works by rendering a Line from that empty gameobject to the object of interest.